# Arithmetic expression before the equal sign

Tags: java

Can you put the equal sign before the arithmetic expression in java eg.And why can't you put it this way. Is there any different meaning

```
ctr =+ 1;
ctr =- 1;
ctr =* 1;
ctr =/ 1;
// instead of 
ctr += 1;
ctr -=1;
ctr /= 1;
ctr *= 1;
```

Comment: try to compile it and see for yourself.

Comment: `ctr =+ 1` is `ctr = +1`, e.g. positive one, not `add one to ctr`.

Comment: It is not an "equal sign", it is the *assignment operator*.  In Java the "equals sign" is "==", as use for boolean and logical statements.

Comment: Those are two different operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your so called *equal sign (=)* is actually [assignment operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)) in programming world. Equal sign is *double equal* `==` which may use in logical opeartion.

```
ctr =+ 1; // means, assign positive 1 into ctr, Compile fine
ctr =- 1; // means, assign negative 1 into ctr, Compile fine
ctr =* 1; //Compilation error like this: illegal start of expression
ctr =/ 1; //Compilation error like this: illegal start of expression
```

For the followings,

```
ctr += 1; // means, ctr = ctr +1, Compile fine
ctr -=1;  // means, ctr = ctr -1, Compile fine
ctr /= 1; // means, ctr = ctr /1, Compile fine
ctr *= 1; // means, ctr = ctr *1, Compile fine
```

You may get garbage unless you initialize `ctr` first.

Answer (score 2):

No because that's how the language is defined. Note that the following will compile:

```
ctr =+ 1;
ctr =- 1;
```

only because it is equivalent to:

```
ctr = +1;
ctr = -1;
```